# VueJS filter doesn't work in v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I have an error on VueJS with a filter added in a v-for from an Axios response and doesn't understand how to solve it. The filter **set_marked** return a **undefined** value if i made a **console.log** on the **value** variable.

Here's the HTML:

```
<main id="app">
  <div v-for="item in productList" :key="item.id">
  <header>
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
  </header>
  <article class="product-card">
      {{ item.content | set_marked  }}
  </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    productList: []
  },
  created: function() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.getPostsViaREST();
  },
  filters: {
    set_marked: function(value) {
      return marked(value);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPostsViaREST: function() {
      axios.get("https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/itrxz5hv6y21/environments/master/entries/1Lv0RTu6v60uwu0w2g2ggM?access_token=a2db6d0bc4221793fc97ff393e541f39db5a65002beef0061adc607ae959abde")
           .then(response => {
              this.productList = response.data;
            });
    }
  }
})
```

You can also try it on my codepen:
https://codepen.io/bhenbe/pen/deYRpg/

Thank you for your help !

Comment: and what is `marked` function?

Comment: it's another library i add to show a markdown content: 
https://github.com/markedjs/marked

Comment: so why not include it in the demo?

Comment: it not seems to be the problem. My error occurs just before the marked function call.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating with `v-for` on `productList`, but in your code `productList` is not an array but an object (a dictionary in other words). In fact if you look at it, it has this structure:

```
{
    "sys": {
        "space": {
            "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Space",
                "id": "itrxz5hv6y21"
            }
        },
        "id": "1Lv0RTu6v60uwu0w2g2ggM",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2017-01-22T18:24:49.677Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-01-22T18:24:49.677Z",
        "environment": {
            "sys": {
                "id": "master",
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Environment"
            }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
            "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "ContentType",
                "id": "page"
            }
        },
        "locale": "fr-BE"
    },
    "fields": {
        "title": "Retour sur douze années de design",
        "content": "Douze années ... vie."
    }
}
```

Iterating through it, on the first iteration will assign to `item` the value of the `"sys"` key, which is:

```
{
    "space": {
        "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "itrxz5hv6y21"
        }
    },
    "id": "1Lv0RTu6v60uwu0w2g2ggM",
    "type": "Entry",
    ...
    "locale": "fr-BE"
},
```

and on the second iteration the value of the `"fields"` key, which has the value:

```
{
    "title": "Retour sur douze années de design",
    "content": "Douze années ... vie."
}
```

Since you are accessing `item.title` and `item.content`, and `title` and `content` keys are not present in the first object, but only in the second, in the first iteration they will be `undefined`. So, in the first iteration you are passing `undefined` as the value of `item.content` to the `set_marked` filter.

`productList` is the response to the `GET` request, which as we have seen is not returning an array but an object.

If you add to the filter the check `if (!value) return '';` it will work, but you are just hiding the problem of the discrepancy between what the API returns and what you are expecting.

If you build `productList` as an array by filtering through the sub-objects of `result.data` and keeping only those containing `title` and `contents` fields, it works:

```js
function marked(value) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    productList: []
  },
  created: function() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.getPostsViaREST();
  },
  filters: {
    set_marked: function(value) {
      // console.log(value);
      return marked(value);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPostsViaREST: function() {
        axios.get("https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/itrxz5hv6y21/environments/master/entries/1Lv0RTu6v60uwu0w2g2ggM?access_token=a2db6d0bc4221793fc97ff393e541f39db5a65002beef0061adc607ae959abde")
           .then(response => {
              // this.productList = response.data;
              let data = response.data;
              let productList = [], key;
              for (key in data) {
                let val = data[key];
                if ((val.title !== undefined) && (val.content !== undefined)) {
                  productList.push(val);
                }
              }
              this.productList = productList;
            });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

body{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

#app > div{
  max-width: 68ch;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <div v-for="item in productList" :key="item.id">
  <header>
    <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
  </header>
  <article class="product-card" v-html="$options.filters.set_marked(item.content)"></article>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I just found this code but i'm very disappointed. I don't know why without this code :
if (!value) return '';
value = value.toString();

the value is undefined... The last problem is that the html is escaped...

Comment: probably some `item` records in `productList` are missing the `content` field. Check with the dev tools the response from the `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find in the documentation the solution.

I must add the following code to the filter set_marked to work properly:

```
if (!value) return '';
value = value.toString();
```

I currently don't know why this additional lines are required.

I had a second problem because the returned html is escaped by VueJS.
The easiest way to avoid this issue is to used the v-html directive.
To apply a filter in the v-html directive, you must use this syntax :

```
v-html="$options.filters.set_marked(item.content)"
```

You can find my pen here : https://codepen.io/bhenbe/pen/deYRpg

Comment: The first part is *not* the actual solution to your problem: those lines are only a guard against null/undefined values and values that are not strings, but you are only circumventing the actual problem, which is the mismatch between you expecting an array in `v-for` and the object nature of `response.data`

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your answer.

The filter return a "undefined" value for the value variable, passed as parameter of the filter. 

If i add the two lines i specified in my answer, value return the correct string. It's like a temporary result and i don't really understand why... I add two console.log in the codepen. If you take a look at the console, the first result return "undefined" and a error message for a too long value at the second time.

If you can help to understand why it works like it, i really appreciate your feedback !

Comment: yes, it returns `undefined` for the reason that I explained in my answer below. I'll try to modify it and explain the problem in a more clear way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just create a method when I need filtering and then use it when needed in my component.

ie:

```
    methods: {
    getPostsViaREST: function() {
      axios.get("https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/itrxz5hv6y21/environments/master/entries/1Lv0RTu6v60uwu0w2g2ggM?access_token=a2db6d0bc4221793fc97ff393e541f39db5a65002beef0061adc607ae959abde")
           .then(response => {
              this.productList = response.data;
            });
    },
    filterPost(post) {
     return _.toUpper(post);
    }
  }
```

And then in your component:

```
 <h1>{{ filterPost(item.title) }}</h1>
```

Find here the full example:

https://codepen.io/Venomzzz/pen/mLrQVm?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Filters and Methods seems to called twice if i add a console.log. I'll go further in the process of VueJS to undestand why.

Comment: Could you elaborate? That's not a "filter", I just prefixed the method with filter, apologies if that seemed confusing.

Comment: No sorry, your example is clear. The thing i don't understand is if i add a console.log to your filterPost method, i see it's called twice. One time undefined and a second time with the good value of the variable. i don't see in the process of vuejs why and where it's explained so i'm disappointed with the result